# scala iterator hasNext random behaviour

Tags: scala

```
var intList = Iterator(range(1,10))
println("data"+intList)
println(intList.hasNext)
```

Last line gives True, whereas for

```
var intList = Iterator(range(1,10))
println("data"+intList.toList)
println(intList.hasNext)
```

Last line give False

Why even if intList is immutable I am not assigning it to any new variable.

Answer (score 5):

You're right that lists are immutable in Scala. However, your `intList` is not a list; it's an [`Iterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html), which uses `next()` to iterate and is mutable.

```
println("data " + intList)
```

This prints out a representation of the iterator. It probably says something like "non-empty iterator". All it needs to do is call `hasNext`, which changes nothing.

```
println("data " + intList.toList)
```

`toList` is a method (don't let the lack of parentheses fool you; everything you call on an object is a method in Scala), and exhausts the iterator, which means it calls `next()` until there's nothing left. Then your iterator is empty, so `hasNext` rightly tells you that there is no next value.